# springboot keeps coming to an null value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

```
 public Account(BaseEntityBuilder<?, ?> b, String email, String name, String nickname, String pwd, UserRole usertype,
        String userf1, String userf2, String userf3, String userf4, String userf5, String filetype) {
    super(b);
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
    this.nickname = nickname;
    this.pwd = pwd;
    this.usertype = usertype;
    this.userf1 = userf1;
    this.userf2 = userf2;
    this.userf3 = userf3;
    this.userf4 = userf4;
    this.userf5 = userf5;
    this.filetype = filetype;
}
```

`code`

```
public interface SpringReadFileService {

List<Account> findAll();

boolean saveDataFromUploadfile(MultipartFile file);
```

}
`code`

```
   List<Account> users = springReadFileService.findAll();
                    
            for(int i = 0; i< users.size(); ++i) {
                
            String a =  users.get(i).getEmail();
                        
            }
```

`code`

In this way, I'm trying to get only all email value among the values in the account array, but it keeps coming to an empty value. Can't I bring it like this? I want to get the value of all the emails in the data.

Comment: What exactly is `null`? Also if you just want all the emails you should select just the emails with a custom query.

Comment: i mean ,The string a does not contain data.

Comment: Then the email is just empty. With a custom query you can filter for `is not null` to avoid those.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am having a hard time because I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand your question:

1. You are using `findAll` of a Spring Data JPA repository in order to load all `Account` instances.
2. You are only interested in the non empty email addresses.

Define your repository as

```java
class AccountRepository<Account, Long> { // replace Long with the type of the primary key
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT email FROM Account WHERE email IS NOT NULL")
    String findAllEmails();
}
```

Then use `findAllEmails` to get the required result.
There are a couple of variants of the JPQL statement depending on what you want:

- If you want duplicates or email is unique through some constraint drop the `DISTINCT`
- If you also have empty but not null emails, i.e. emails of length 0 you might want to add  `AND email <> ''` to the query.